# How to calculate this integral to find the range of u?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fresnel-integrals

I have a integral $$ f(u)= \int_{-n/2}^{n/2} \int_{-n/2}^{n/2} e^{j u \pi ((x^2+y^2)- (ax+by)^2) } d_x d_y,$$ where $n>0,u>0$, and $a , b \in [0,1]$.
I want to find the range of $u$ to make $ |f(u) | \leq \beta$, where $\beta$ is a given threshold.
How can I simplify it?  Could anyone give some hints, textbooks, or comments? Thanks very much!

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the ambiguity.